# What would be the correct way for un-ordered list inside of un-ordered list?

Tags: html, html-lists

Example:

[image]

I am wondering what would be the correct way to code an un-ordered list inside of an unordered list like the design above.

I am assuming that it would be like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#"> site 2  </a>
   <ul> 
     <li> <a href="#"> link 1 </a></li>
     <li> <a href="#"> link 2 </a></li>
     <li> <a href="#"> link 3 </a></li>
  </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#"> site 2  </a>
   <ul> 
     <li> <a href="#"> link 1 </a></li>
     <li> <a href="#"> link 2 </a></li>
     <li> <a href="#"> link 3 </a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li> blah </li>
  <ul>
     <li> inside list item </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Would this be the correct way, if not what would it?

Comment: The second `<ul>` tag must be closed before the first `<li>` tag is closed (same for the second inner list), otherwise this is not even valid HTML.

Comment: @The Nail: I just checked the HTML validator, nested lists have to be defined *inside* a list item. `document type does not allow element "UL" here; assuming missing "LI" start-tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both methods will render correctly in the browser, only one method appears to be valid HTML.

**Invalid:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

**Valid:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li><ul>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li>Test Test
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Trippy: Yes, and ul ul is not.

Comment: Okay and I'm assuming  ul li a and ul li ul is both valid? (archor then the list inside of li)

Comment: @Trippy: Yes, you can put an anchor inside of a list item, no problem. Any inline element can be placed inside a list item.

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote would indeed produce an unordered list inside an unordered list. But to make it look as in the picture you would have to do some extra work that is not listed in the example.

Comment: I am planning to hide the inside list at some point when a user clicks another title. Is that what you mean't? I pretty know how to code this exactly, I just don't know the correct way to format the HTML for it d:

Comment: I'm talking about all of the format of the list, which is not shown in the code example you wrote.